# Google Maps Integration: Unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Encountered the following error while using Google Maps for my iOS app.

`+[GMSx_GMPCClientVectorTileExtensionsRoot indoorBuildingMetadata]: unrecognized selector sent to class`

What would possibly be the reason?

Comment: same problem here

Comment: facing same issue, anyone found solution?

Comment: We are having the exactly same problem but only when the app is built in release mode. Still not solution found.